# Applying hover effect after an animation

Tags: css, animation, hover

I have an animation applied to

```
`une
 {margin-top: 245px;margin-left: 545px; -webkit-animation:move ease 1 forwards 15s 3s;  -moz-animation:move ease 1 forwards 15s 3s ;animation:move ease 1 forwards 15s 3s ;


-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; -o-transition: all 1s ease;}`
```

so after this i want to be able to hover on this element (which is an image) in order to either change it's scale or make another image apper, however no matter what i do it is not working.
so let's say
    une:hover{-webkit-transform:scale(1;1)}     is not working
anyone any ideas/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar for my site, check it out- http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/v7k7f/10/

Here's a much simpler version- http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/MzSkJ/1/

```
.une {
    position:absolute; /* use position rather than margin */
    top:--px;
    left:--px;
    -webkit-animation:lightSpeedIn 1s;
    -moz-animation:lightSpeedIn 1s;
    animation:lightSpeedIn 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
}
.une:hover {
    transform-origin:top; /* keeps it on the viewable screen */
    transform:scale(2.5);
}
```

I think the `transform-origin` and `position` may have been the missing pieces, but I'd need to see the animation to be sure.

also the animation syntax looks a little off. [Try using the formal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation)-

```
animation: name duration easing delay iteration-count direction fill-mode;
```